# SCNText Position when run on iOS 9 and iOS 10 gave different result

Tags: scntext

I have created a project and tested on

- iPad real Device (iOS 9.3.5)
- iPad Pro Simulator (iOS 10.2)

The results are different for the SCNText locations, it seems that every SCNText when run on iOS 10.2 are vertically offset at some constant distance and run on iOS 9.3.5 seems to give the correct results.

This is the testing code:

```
    let testText = SCNText(string: "ABCDEF", extrusionDepth: 0)
    testText.font = font
    let txtNd = SCNNode(geometry: testText)
    txtNd.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
    rootNode.addChildNode(txtNd)

    let bMax = txtNd.boundingBox.max
    let bMin = txtNd.boundingBox.min
    print("\(bMax)\n\(bMin)")
```

and the console print output

iOS 9.3.5 is

SCNVector3(x: 0.69833982, y: 0.142382815, z: 0.0)

SCNVector3(x: 0.00214843755, y: -0.00234375009, z: 0.0)

iOS 10.2 is

SCNVector3(x: 0.69833982, y: 1.14238286, z: 0.0)

SCNVector3(x: 0.00214843755, y: 0.997656226, z: 0.0)

[screen shot iOS 9.3.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsFnM.jpg)
[screen shot iOS 10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZERK.png)